# Plotly dash creating columns based on user selection

Tags: python, html, plotly, plotly-dash, plotly-python

I am working on a selection menu where the user can select the number of experiments they want to compare/see. Depending on this number I would like to adapt the number of columns that appear, being one for each experiment. In the image below an example of the menu with one experiment can be seen. However, I would like these dropdowns to duplicate if the user selects two experiments having them in side-to-side columns.

Here is an example of one column and one experiment:
[image: example with one column and one experiment]

The code I have so far is the following:

```
# Load Data
df = px.data.tips()

external_stylesheets = ["https://codepen.io/chriddyp/pen/bWLwgP.css"] 

# Build App
app = JupyterDash(__name__,  external_stylesheets=external_stylesheets)

app.layout = html.Div([
    # first row - selecting the number of experiments
     html.Div([
        html.I("Select the number of experiments you want to compare (min - 2 and max - 10):"),
        html.Br(),
        
        # input box for the number of experiments
        dcc.Input(id="num_exp" , type='number', min = 2, max = 10, placeholder="No of experiments"),
        html.Div(id="output")
        ], style = {'width': '100%'}
    ),
    
    # second row - where the experiments are organized in columns
    html.Div([
        html.Label([
            html.I("X axis "),
            dcc.Dropdown(
                id = 'dd_axis', 
                clearable = False,
                placeholder = 'Select property x-axis',
                options=[
                    {'label': i, 'value': i}
                    for i in properties
                ], 
                style={
                    'width': '100%'
                })
        ]),
        html.Label([
            html.I("Y Axis "),
            dcc.Dropdown(
                id = 'dd_yaxis',
                clearable = False,
                placeholder = 'Select property y-axis',
                options=[ ], 
                disabled = False)
        ])        
    ], style = {'display': 'inline-block', 'vertical-align': 'top', 'margin-left': '3vw', 'margin-top': '3vw', 'width': '50%'})
])

@app.callback(
 Output("output", "children"),
    # number of experiments input 
    Input("num_exp", "value"),
)

def update_output(test_type):
    in_testtype = test_type
    return u'{} experiments'.format(test_type)

def cb_render(*vals):
    return " | ".join((str(val) for val in vals if val))
```

Can you help me adding more dropdown menus to the side and dividing the second row in columns based in the user selection?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this by using `dbc.Col` and `dbc.Row`.

In your layout, have a `Div` and within it an empty `dbc.Row` that will be used to populate its `children` attribute with columns.

Then, in the callback that is triggered by the input box value, have a loop that returns the number of columns you want, with the relevant code for the `dbc.Col` and what you'd like to display in it.

Here's a worked-up example of your original code:

```py
import dash
from dash import dcc, html
import dash_bootstrap_components as dbc
from dash.dependencies import Input, Output


app = dash.Dash(external_stylesheets=[dbc.themes.BOOTSTRAP])

properties = ["a", "b", "c"]

app.layout = html.Div([
    # first row - selecting the number of experiments
    html.Div([
        html.I(
            "Select the number of experiments you want to compare (min - 2 and max - 10):"),
        html.Br(),
        # input box for the number of experiments
        dcc.Input(id="num_exp", value=2, type='number', min=2,
                  max=10, placeholder="No of experiments"),
        html.Div([
            dbc.Row([], id="output")
        ])
    ], style={'width': '100%'}
    ),
])


@app.callback(
    Output("output", "children"),
    # number of experiments input
    Input("num_exp", "value"),
)
def update_output(test_type):
    columns_list = []
    letters = "xyzabcdefg"
    for i in range(test_type):
        columns_list.append(
            dbc.Col([
                html.Label([
                    html.I(f"{letters[i].upper()} axis "),
                    dcc.Dropdown(
                        id=f'{letters[i]}_axis',
                        clearable=False,
                        placeholder=f'Select property {letters[i]}-axis',
                        options=[
                            {'label': i, 'value': i}
                            for i in properties
                        ],
                        style={
                            'width': '100%'
                        })
                ])
            ])
        )
    return columns_list


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run_server(debug=True)
```

Comment: Thanks! However, I get this error when running your code: * Serving Flask app '__main__' (lazy loading)
 * Environment: production
   WARNING: This is a development server. Do not use it in a production deployment.
   Use a production WSGI server instead.
 * Debug mode: on
An exception has occurred, use %tb to see the full traceback.

SystemExit: 1   - Do you know why?

Comment: It could be because the input will fail when you input '1' or anything greater than '10'. You should get the error in that stack strace where you run the server, do you see an error output?

Comment: It's working now! Thank you :) I am going to modify it so that it works with columns but you really helped!

Comment: Hi again, I have realized that when modifying the experiments number, although the row population works, the following TypeError appears: 'NoneType' object cannot be interpreted as an integer 'NoneType' object cannot be interpreted as an integer (in the `for i in range(test_type):` line of code). I have tried casting to an integer but still detects the object as NoneType